Can't pip install pystan on Mac
When I try to pip install pystan I get the following error:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Cython>=0.22 and NumPy are required.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I have confirmed that both Cython>=0.22 and NumPy are already installed so I am not sure what step to take next.
Perhaps the issue is that I have an M1 Mac. The pystan installation page lists x86-64 CPU as a requirement. https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Looks like there are numerous issues with pystan including but not limited to its (apparent) reliance on Intel. Their installation suggestion (on PyPI) to use pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile" is flawed as pip 24.0 doesn't support --install-option

You need to install httpstan from source first:

download source code from https://github.com/stan-dev/httpstan
build from source

make

# Build the httpstan wheel on your system
python3 -m pip install poetry
python3 -m poetry build

# Install the wheel
python3 -m pip install dist/*.whl


pip install pystan --no-binary pystan

https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-run-pystan-on-macos-with-apple-silicon-chips-apple-m1-m2-etc

I seem to have an irreconcilable conflict: pystan requires clikit which requires crashtest<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 while pystan also requires httpstan-4.12.0 which requires cleo which requires crashtest<0.5.0,>=0.4.1. So there is no version of crashtest that satisfies both
